# MediaWiki / OOUI: SelectWidget for multiple selections?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, oojs-ui

is there a class similar to a SelectWidget which allows to select multiple items from a list in the OOUI library? I want to use that in a MediaWiki VisualEditor instance I'm extending.

I guess I can also rewrite SelectWidget myself, but yeah maybe there's a solution already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOUI appears to have only [CapsuleMultiselectWidget](https://doc.wikimedia.org/oojs-ui/master/demos/) (tag list / capsule control).

Also, you should note this is a [JS-only widget](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T135340) (no PHP implementation, or "PHP pendant" in OOUI-speak).

After quite an extensive search, it appears there's no simpler multi-select dropdown - there are a few open tasks to implement one:

- [T91147](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T91147): Create a generalised multi-select widget
- [T108489](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T108489): Generalise CapsuleMultiselectWidget into a MultiselectWidget
- [T117782](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T117782): Implement CheckboxMultiselectWidget (and CheckboxMultiselectInputWidget)

Comment: Well, I used the existing Select Widget and adjusted it so that multiple items can be selected. Not too much work. If someone is interested, I can post it here when I'll lay my hands on the project the next time.

Comment: @Jacob S, that'd be nice - if you do that, I'll link to this question from the relevant issue.

Comment: That's how I changed it: http://pasted.co/3d2d57d8
I only changed stuff until it did what I wanted it to do; so it's likely there are some functionalities I didn't refactor yet. It's also possible that I did some dumb decisions there as I'm new to JS/web development in general.

Comment: Notice, that CapsuleMultiselectWidget was replaced by superior TagMultiselectWidget in latest version of OOUI https://doc.wikimedia.org/oojs-ui/master/demos/?page=widgets&theme=wikimediaui&direction=ltr&platform=desktop#TagMultiselectWidget-allowArbitrary-inline-input-placeholder